# change ahref color in th but not in tr

Tags: html, css

I have a table where the table header contains an a href as well as each tr.  I want to change the color of the th ahref without affecting the color of the ahref in the tr.  How can I go about this?

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <a href="/Index">Index</a>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <a href="/Index2">Index</a>
  </tr>
</table>



table.Documents th
{
    color: Black;
}
```

does not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
table th a {
    color: black; //wont apply to td a
}
```

Also, your html is badly formed. It should be:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a href="/Index2">Index</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And if you want to use the class "Documents":

```
<table class="Documents">
```